# Elasticsearch NEST and Count with Wildcards

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have ES and nest working and the search works for a wild card. I want to count the number of records and count I have seen is allowed for an exact match but I want a "like" match (in sql - as an analogy ). 
The code below returns nothing. Has anyone any ideas?

```
var searchDataCount = client.Count<SearchRow>(s => s.Index("myindex").AllTypes().
Query(q => q.QueryString(qs => qs.OnFields(j => j.searchstring).Query(@searchString))));

var searchDataResults = client.Search<SearchRow>(s =>s.Index("myindex").AllTypes().
From(startcount).Size(recordsize). Query(q => q.
QueryString(qs => qs.OnFields(j => j.searchstring).Query(@searchString))));
```

Answer (score 0):

possibly you can use the same query module to perform the search which is similiar to LIKE queries in sql by adding "*" in search query

example:

if you are searching for a string as 'data%' in sql, that can be queries in Elastcisearch as follows

```
            var searchDataResults = client
            .Search<SearchRow>(s => s.Index("myindex")
                .AllTypes()
                .From(startcount)
                .Size(recordsize)
                .Query(q => q
                    .QueryString(qs => qs
                        .OnFields(j => j.searchstring)
                        .Query("data*"))));
```

similiar cases: sql=>Elasticsearch

```
data% => data*
%data => *data
%data% => *data*
```

Comment: Yes I understand that is possible but client.Count does not work at all and I have tried using Aggregations too with ValueCount which also fails. What I want is the equivalent of select count(*) from table where col like '%test%' in ES. I have the search working (with no count) but the count part will not work.

Comment: you can do the same thing with count query

Comment: The code here - http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/core/count.html - does not work for me. Even client.count() fails but the client.search<searchrow> works. What is very frustrating is no error message is returned. The object just says "does not exist" for the return obj.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in the default index being a different one. Here is post which gave me the idea - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1404. The actual code -

```
 settings = new ConnectionSettings(node, defaultIndex: "myindex");
```

The default index needed to match the index in the client.count query.